# Draggable elements in nested click jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Following @amphetamachine advice from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931580/280914) I was able to handle nested clicks using jQuery. Now the drag feature that was previously working is now not working after implementing the delegates.

The concept still the same an empty DIV that once it will it will add another DIV inside itself and if that created DIV is click it is then remove. I use a variable to determine if I want to drag the DIV or to remove it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#container').on('click', function(e){

  // Add other DIV
  $( this ).append('<div class="other">XYZ</div>');

  e.stopPropagation();

  // Remove other DIV
  $('div.other').bind('click', function(event){

    if (global_variable == 'drag') {
      $( this ).draggable({cursor:'move'});
    }
    else {
      $( this ).remove();
    }

    event.stopPropagation();

  });

});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer. Here is the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/9sbnq3pv/1/

I just needed to do:

```
    // Add other DIV
    var div = $('<div class="other">XYZ</div>');
        div.draggable({cursor:'move'});
    $(this).append(div);
```

Instead of:

```
  // Add other DIV
  $( this ).append('<div class="other">XYZ</div>');
```

Thank you